# When the module is uploaded to maven, the files in the jar are lost

Tags: android, maven, jar

When the module is packaged as an aar and uploaded to maven, the jar in the module is modified and the configuration file and custom properties file in the jar are lost；
my module:[The jar structure Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OeRc.png)

My jar contains "xx.xml" "xx.providers"  "xx" files
The files in these jar packages are normally packaged into apk when they are dependent as modules

When I uploaded the aar package to maven and then relied on it in the project, the files in the jar package would not be packaged into apk. I looked at the generated aar files, and the jars included in these aar files did not contain these files

Comment: Please read how to formulate a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide at least your .pom and how you package/deploy your artifacts in your maven repository.